# Создание массива массивов, который хранит ранее созданные массивы. JAVA

Tags: java, массивы

Необходимо создать массив, который хранит значения ранее созданных массивов.

```
char[] a = new char[100];
char[] b = new char[100];
char[] c = new char[100];

char[][] x = new char[1][3]; // здесь должны храниться a[] b[] и c[].
```

как ни пытался , ничего не получалось

Comment: Потому, что не хватает места?

Answer (score 4):

У вас неверная инициализация:

```
char[][] x = new char[1][3];
```

первое число - это количество одномерных массивов, в вашем случае их 3, второе число - количество элементов в одномерном массиве, в вашем случае их 100. Посколько вы всё равно будете присваивать целый массив в итоге в x[i], то второй размер можно даже опустить:

```
public static void main(String args []) {
    char[] a = new char[100];
    char[] b = new char[100];
    char[] c = new char[100];

    Arrays.fill(a, 'a');
    Arrays.fill(b, 'b');
    Arrays.fill(c, 'c');

    char[][] x = new char[3][];
    x[0] = a;
    x[1] = b;
    x[2] = c;
    Arrays.stream(x).map(Arrays::toString).forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

> [a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a...
>
> [b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b...
>
> [c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c...